# Simultaneous button pressing for mobile devices Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game for mobile phones in Unity. I have four buttons from Boxcollider and Rect. I need an event where I can drive forward and turn at the same time.

This event doesn't work for me:

```
                         if (IsTouchingButton(button1_Thrt, touch.position))
                         {
                             Debug.Log("Touching button 1");
                             Thrt = true;
                         }
```

Here is my code, please help me

```
public class BikeScript : MonoBehaviour
 {
     WheelJoint2D[] wheelJoints;
     JointMotor2D BackTire;
 
     public GameObject button1_Thrt;
     public GameObject button2_Brake;
     public GameObject button3_Left;
     public GameObject button4_Right;
 
     public bool Thrt = false;
     public bool Brake = false;
     public bool Left = false;
     public bool Right = false; 
      
     private bool IsTouchingButton(GameObject button, Vector2 touchPosition)
     {
         if (button == null)
             return false;
 
         Vector3 buttonScreenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(button.transform.position);
 
         return RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint(button.GetComponent<RectTransform>(), touchPosition);
     }
 
     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         if (Input.touchCount > 0)
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
             {
                 Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
 
                 if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                 {
                     Debug.Log("Touch began at position: " + touch.position);
 
                     if (IsTouchingButton(button1_Thrt, touch.position))
                     {
                         Debug.Log("Touching button 1");
                         Thrt = true;
                     }
                     else if (IsTouchingButton(button2_Brake, touch.position))
                     {
                         Debug.Log("Touching button 2");
                         Brake = true;
                     }
                     else if (IsTouchingButton(button3_Left, touch.position))
                     {
                         Debug.Log("Touching button 3");
                         Left = true;
                     }
                     else if (IsTouchingButton(button4_Right, touch.position))
                     {
                         Debug.Log("Touching button 4");
                         Right = true;
                     }
                 }
                 else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                 {
                     Debug.Log("Touch moved at position: " + touch.position);
                 }
                 else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                 {
                     Debug.Log("Touch ended at position: " + touch.position);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 
 }
```

Or please send me where I can see the script to perform my tasks.

I need help! The debugger does not see the button

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using the "new" input system in Unity. Makes it less complicated so you can even just delete most of this code. Here you have a video about Touch Input with it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERAN5KBy2Gs

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm looking at, every line of code you wrote makes sense. However, I noticed something that might be the cause of your issue.

Because `FixedUpdate()` is frame independent, the game might not recognize the touch events at the frame update time.

> `MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate`  Frame-rate independent MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate message for physics calculations. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html

Try changing `void FixedUpdate()` with `void Update()` and see if it makes any difference.